# C++ metaprogramming,why and when should be used?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I am reading Abrahams,Gurtovoy book about C++ metaprogramming. I must admit that I do not understand properly there explanation for using template metaprogramming. For example:

> You want the code to be expressed in terms of the abstractions of the problem domain.

Or:

> You would otherwise have to write a great deal of boilerplate implementation code.

Could someone elaborate on this?

Comment: Looking at the first chapter on Amazon, I see that it right away begins by explaining this at length and with examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too use C++ for scientific computing and, yes, template meta-programming comes in very helpful. One use is to help with implementations of general purpose numerical methods. A typical example is `std::sort`, which is an abstraction of sorting in such a way that it works for whatever you want to sort.

Similarly, you may write, say, a templated spline interpolation that can interpolate y(x) for any type `x` that implements the concept of a scalar (orderable, operators `+` `-` `*`) and type `y` that is interpolateable (allows `y+y`, `y-y`, `y*x`). Once you have established such a template, you can use it to interpolate, say, some matrix type over a `double` (representing time, for instance) without any further adaptations: it just works immediately (the compiler must do some work, though).

Answer (score 1):

> You want the code to be expressed in terms of the abstractions of the problem domain.

Template Metaprogramming (TMP) can be used to separate and abstract different tasks in your code. For example, [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) is implemented so as to be completely agnostic of your (the user's) code. You just have to provide a bit of glue, in the form of a `serialize()` member function, and Boost.Serialize will be able to work with your class seamlessly. And since this is all at compile-time, this flexibility does not come at any runtime cost (as opposed to polymorphism).

> You would otherwise have to write a great deal of boilerplate implementation code.

TMP techniques can be used to generate code, and to efficiently factorize common code. For example, [Boost.Intrusive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/intrusive/usage.html) lets you "import" behaviour in your classes (by various means, such as inheritance or type traits), and that is nothing else than generating code and injecting it into your class to transform it into, for example, a list node.

Comment: Thanks.I intend to use C++ for scientific computation,Is serialization used for this?

Comment: @RichardRublev These are two example off the top of my head, I don't know if these particular two can be of use to you. However, scientific computation looks like a domain that could use TMP for compile-time abstraction, and really benefit from the speed boost (compared to "classic", polymorphism-driven abstraction).